# Why is the base constructor called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Alright, I have a very basic question, so please go easy on me.
In the following code:

```
#include<iostream>    

class base
{
      public:
             base() { std::cout << "Base()" << std::endl; }
};

class derived: base {
      public:
             derived() { std::cout << "Derived()" << std::endl; }
             };
int main() {
derived d;
}
```

The output is:

> Base()
>
> Derived()

I would like to know why the constructor of the `base` class is called even though I am creating an object of the `derived` class? I could not find a proper answer in the `FAQ`.

Comment: I'd start by reading something like [this](http://www.desy.de/gna/html/cc/Tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: The purpose of a constructor is to make the object usable. If you didn't call the base constructor, every derived class would have to perform every bit of setup required by every one of it's base classes to make the object usable...  Which doesn't play well with encapsulation etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constructor of the `base` class is called to initialize `base` class subobject that contained in the `derived`. This is how inheritance works, this makes it easier to follow the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Consider the following:

```
class base
{
public:
  base() : x(10) { std::cout << "Base()" << std::endl; }
private:
   int x;
};

class derived: base {
public:
  derived() { std::cout << "Derived()" << std::endl; }
};
```

How you would initialize member `base::x` without calling constructor of the base class?

---

Nevertheless you should note that when you use *virtual inheritance* you should call the constructor of the common base manually.

Comment: `virtual inheritance` - That hit the spot.

Answer (score 5):

A derived object, by definition, *is* a base object as well.

Answer (score 3):

A `Derived` object should always be able to be used in place of a `Base` object. If `Base` has private members that need to be properly initialized for `Base` to work, that is probably done in the constructor, so the `Base` constructor should always be called.